# How to change mat-icon size in Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

This question comes from the Material2 Github [repo](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4422#issuecomment-300309224).

I still have problems to style a Material component that is wrapped in a custom component.

I have a `<logo>` component that contains `<md-icon svgIcon="logo"></md-icon>`

Adding:

```
:host { 
   .mat-icon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 56px;
  }
}
```

Will not apply to the Material component inside my custom component.

Comment: "Within" or "on"? The `:host` syntax is meant to apply to the component itself, and **not** to it's children. Sounds like you have a "child" of `md-icon`, and that means you just want to adjust the css with just the plain class and not using `:host`

Comment: The `width`/`height`/`font-size` overrides are better suited for the built-in material icons. Unfortunately, changing the font size won't work when you're using the `svgIcon`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**UPDATE: 2019-05-22**

Newer versions of Material Design has the option to set `[inline]="true"` as a property on the HTML element.

I would recommend using that approach instead.

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up" inline="true"></mat-icon>
```

When using this, the icon will inherit from the parent container!

GLHF! :)

---

I have been getting some questions about this so I just wanted to make a clearer example of how to use it...

```scss
/* 1. Add this mixin to a "global" scss */

@mixin md-icon-size($size: 24px) {
  font-size: $size;
  height: $size;
  width: $size;
  line-height: $size;
}

/* 2. Then use it like this in you component scss */

mat-icon {
  @include md-icon-size(32px);
}
```

example usage

```html
<mat-icon class="myIcon" svgIcon="search"></mat-icon>
```

```scss
:host {
  .myIcon {
    &mat-icon {
      @include md-icon-size(32px);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution uses SCSS, what would be the vanilla CSS solution? Furthermore, this only changes the bounding-box size of the wrapper `<md-icon>` element, not the `<svg>` element contained within.

Comment: note that this will have unexpected behavior when using `em` unit, because em relates on the element's `font-size`. So `@include md-icon-size(3em);` will actually make it `9em`

Comment: I agree to @GerardoFigueroa 's point. It is not changing the size of the svg, its just changing the size of the bounding box.

Comment: Adding !important will do the job, like this font-size: $size !important;

Answer (score 121):

In my case, this works perfectly. I use newest material (6.2.0)

CSS:

```
.icon {
    font-size: 36px;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="icon">
    <mat-icon [inline]="true">done</mat-icon>
  </div>
```

The main thing is to set: `[inline]="true"`

From [the API](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api):

> @Input() inline: boolean - Whether the icon should be inlined,
>   automatically sizing the icon to match the font size of the element
>   the icon is contained in.

Comment: This is the better solution now. No need for all the other mix-ins.

Comment: Works for font icons, not for SVG

Comment: I agree, `[inline]="true"` seems to be a more elegant solution, if the matched font-size in the size we need.

Comment: This works up to a point - If I set my font-size to ~150px or larger, the icon starts going out of the top of its container div.

Comment: Thanks. Even simpler, `<mat-icon inline>more_vert</mat-icon>` just did the trick

Comment: Does not work for me.. my icon is aligned at the top, I want it in the middle.

Comment: @Johannes probably you should try to align it with flex then

Comment: thanks for the [inline]="true"! I have been wrestling with line-height... makes it a LOT easier.

Comment: This almost works for me, but the icons are no longer square. Using the `mixin` approach works with square icons.

Answer (score 37):

I'm using

```html
<mat-icon svgIcon="cellphone-link"></mat-icon>
```

with

```
.mat-icon {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

for resizing the svg element. It was the only working solution for me, where 2 is 200% of the actual size (downsizing to e.g. 0.5 would be possible also).

Setting "height" and "width" was no option for me, because the rendered svg element of the mat-icon component has no viewBox attribute at the moment. But the viewBox attribute is mandatory to make it work with "height" and "width" styling. Maybe the Angular Material team will improve that in future.

**As a side note**:
You can center the mat-icon with a parent wrapper and

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: Great solution. Worked for me!

Comment: That's perfect solution

Answer (score 9):

**Edit: Please see the accepted answer!**

Using it like this works just fine.

```
<md-icon svgIcon="arrow-down" class="size-16"></md-icon>
```

when having defined this in theme css (not in component :host)

```
md-icon.size-16 {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: font-size missing?

Comment: Not in this answer. You might merge your 3 different answers into one?!

Comment: Not a good idea in all cases. I typically choose the answer which is rated highest. In your case: why do you offer 3 different answers?

Comment: I hope it works. I've used this one with added `font-size`. Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 7):

To make sure the icon remains centered within its in-build container (within `<mat-icon>` component) after it is resized, use this solution. **Does not** need a wrapper box nor the `inline=true` property.

HTML

```
<mat-icon class="big">error_outline</mat-icon>
```

CSS

```
.big {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

*Note: You can also use other units, like **px** or **em***

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
@mixin md-icon-size($size: 24px) {
  font-size: $size;
  height: $size;
  width: $size;
}

.material-icons.mat-icon {
  @include md-icon-size(32px);
}
```

Comment: So this does the same as my solution but is more flexible.. so I will convert to this way of doing it :) thx

Comment: `.mat-icon` did the trick

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is caused by inlining the svg without viewBox - preventing all resizing attempts.

Seems to me the alternative is using the iconfont directly:

```
<i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 40px">face</i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me

HTML

```
  <button mat-fab>
    <mat-icon class="md-36" inline aria-label="Home button">
      home
    </mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button mat-fab>
    <mat-icon class="md-48" inline aria-label="Up button">
      expand_less
    </mat-icon>
  </button>
```

CSS

```
.material-icons.md-18 {
  margin-top: -3px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.material-icons.md-24 {
  margin-top: -3px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.material-icons.md-36 {
  margin-top: -3px;
  font-size: 36px;
}
.material-icons.md-48 {
  margin-top: -4px;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

The icons are properly centered and the wrapper div doesn't overflow the fab/button
Not too elegant I guess

Answer (score 0):

One other possible option, if you want to have the option to scale images to any font size up to a maximum (e.g. 300px), the following scss loop would work;

```
@for $i from 1 through 300{
  .iconsize-#{$i}{
    font-size: $i+unquote('px') !important;
    height: $i+unquote('px') !important;
    width: $i+unquote('px') !important;
  };
}
```

If you want to set a minimum size to generate in the compiled CSS, simply change `1` above to the minimum size you'd like and likewise, to change the maximum value, change `300` to whatever maximum value you'd like.

This is particularly handy for the icons as being SVG, they will scale to the size you set (though I've had some trouble getting third-party SVG icons scaling to fit the container, but that's a different issue). If you're like me, you often need to have the majority of icons at a specific size (e.g. menu icons) with some icons being larger (e.g. decorative elements). This loop allows you to easily test different sizes of font up to any size at 1px increments until you find a size that works for you.

**What does this do?**

When your SCSS is compiled to CSS, it will output a loop with the relevant classes from 1 to 300.

**How do I use it?**

To use, simply add the `.iconsize-[x]` class to your `mat-icon`;

```
<mat-icon class="iconsize-45">show_chart</mat-icon>
```

This example will set the icon to be 45px width and height.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting idea but for me I see no case where I would want to limit to a max-size.. and also I would never use !important :P

Comment: @Mackelito The reason to set a max size is simply because you will end up with a huge CSS file (and the logic for a loop requires it). The other option is to use inline properties.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do it (with no extra CSS), the following works fine

```html
    <sup><mat-icon inline="true">info</mat-icon></sup>
<small><mat-icon inline="true">info</mat-icon></small>
<big><mat-icon inline="true">info</mat-icon></big>
```

Please note the `inline="true"` which makes it inherit styling of parent tag

Answer (score 0):

### An alternative solution using the [ngStyle] directive.

When you simply want to overwrite the size of a `mat-icon` only once without making a stylesheet you can also easily do that using the `ngStyle` directive on the `mat-icon` component as follows:

```html
<mat-icon [ngStyle]="{ 'width.px': 64, 'width.px': 64 'font-size.px': 64 }">build</mat-icon>
```

Or when defining the size in your component:

```js
this.size = 64;
```

and then:

```html
<mat-icon [ngStyle]="{ 'width.px': size, 'width.px': size 'font-size.px': size }">build</mat-icon>
```

This solution works because you are adding inline styling on the `mat-icon` host component directly.

### Wrapping the above solution into a custom directive.

The above mentioned solution can be easily wrapped into a directive if you want to reuse the sizing multiple times in your application:

```js
import { Directive, HostBinding, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appIconSize]',
})
export class IconSizeDirective {

  @HostBinding('style.width') @HostBinding('style.height') @HostBinding('style.font-size') @Input('appIconSize') public size: string;
    
}
```

and then:

```html
<mat-icon appIconSize="64px">build</mat-icon>
```

---

[Checkout a working example of both solution in the following StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-icons-i28jpc?file=app%2Ficon-overview-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular Material version 13.3.9.

In my case, both the button and the icon needed css:

```css
.add-button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.mat-icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<button mat-mini-fab class="add-button-container" color="primary"
                                            aria-label="icon button with an add icon">
                                            <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
```