# How to change size of mat-icon on Angular Material?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

mat-icon tag of Angular Material always has default size is 24px. So how to change it ...???

```
.mat-icon {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
fill: currentColor;
height: 24px;
width: 24px;
}
```

Comment: `font-size:40px;`

Comment: or `transform:scale(1.x)`

Comment: See answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43887701/how-to-change-md-icon-size-in-material

Comment: & mat-icon {            
width: 13px;
            height: 13px;
              font-size: unset;
          }

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Since Angular Material uses '**Material Icons**' Font-Family, the icon size depends on **font-size**.

Therefore, if you want to modify the size of the icon then you change its **font-size** in your CSS file.

For example,

For class:

```
.mat-icon {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

For tag:

```
mat-icon {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: in this way the space taken by the icon doesn't increase/decrease, but keep the same, and that could be a problem

Comment: You have to set the `width` and `height` too.

Comment: After setting width and height to a value less that 24px, it looked awkward. I was able to fix it by adjusting the line height property.

Comment: Directly Adding styles attribute to <Span> tag worked too
<mat-icon><span style="font-size: 30px;">screen_lock_landscape</span></mat-icon>

Comment: This worked for me. With the almighty #Tailwind all I had to do is text-[30px] and bang.

Answer (score 238):

font-size tends to mess with the position.  I do something like:

```
<mat-icon class="icon-display">home</mat-icon>
```

CSS:

```
.icon-display {
   transform: scale(2);
}
```

Where the 2 can actually be any number.  2 doubles the original size.

Comment: This must be the selected answer, with this option the space taken by the icon increase correctly.  If we only use font-size the space taken by the icon doesn't increase/decrease

Comment: i was the 70th... sorry

Comment: In my case font-size didn't work as expected. Icon displays at a point and my mouse click event works on other point. So, transform is a better idea in that case.

Comment: see the latter answer from @Shakur.

Comment: this works well for enlarging icons, but not so well for decreasing the size, because the space around the icon stays the same.

Comment: This is not the best way to do that. If you look at ripple effect it changed it origin. Secondly scaling ignores container size so you will have to adjust margins and sizes additionally. I use combination of font-size+width+height+line-height

Answer (score 65):

In order to properly wrap the font apart from setting the font size you also need to adjust the height and width

If you want to do it globally:

```
.mat-icon {
    font-size: 50px;
    height: 50px ;
    width: 50px;
}
```

If you want to apply the size only to certain icons

```css
.customIconSize {
    font-size: 50px;
    height: 50px ;
    width: 50px ;
}
```

And in your HTML template

```html
<button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon class="customIconSize">visibility</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: This should be a right answer

Comment: Thank you @Shakur, yes without the `width` adjustment the icon will not be centered.

Comment: By default the icon has style { font-size: 24px; width: 24px; height: 24px }. So we need to adjust both width and height.

Comment: I have updated the answer with your comments

Comment: this should be the correct answer.

Comment: Nowdays (v14 era) the button component has view encapsulation none, so the above will not work without `!important` (not recommended) or making the block more specific (in terms of CSS). (Because the button has its own component style and component styles are always loaded after the global style.)

Comment: This is the best solution, as using `transform: scale(0.7)` with a value less than 1 dosen't shrink the space.

Comment: thank you! after trying the other answers here, this one worked best for me, because it shrinks the icon size and the space around it

Answer (score 12):

You should also change the width and height so the container matches the font-size.

Depending on your use case a good feature of the mat-icon is a bool input of [inline], set this to true and it will auto size to the element it's contained in.

Answer (score 12):

Create the class name matches to the actual function. It become more easy to remember, use and extend it.

```
.icon-2x {
    transform: scale(2);
}

.icon-3x {
    transform: scale(3);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The "font-size" approach only works for regular (font-based) sizing. Thus it doesn't work for svg icons, which the only way to resize that really worked for me so far was scaling it up/down.

Answer (score -1):

try first using:

```
.mat-icon{
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

If you can't,
try in the following way:

```
.mat-icon {
    width: 10px;
}
```

Good luck !!!