# How to get a check circle icon with a white background color in Angular Material?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

This is the current circle that I have, with the code

```
   <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
          <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 10%">
            <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" style="color:#4CAF50">check_circle</mat-icon>
          </div>
          <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 100%">
              <span class="verify-email2">8 characters mininum</span>
          </div>
      </div>
```

[image: check circle]

what I want to implement is the image below with white background

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **check_circle_outline** instead of check_circle

Comment: and how do we resize a mat icon Sir ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47280483/2900893 this will help you.

Comment: Sir , how do we align the text to the icon ? https://imgur.com/a/G27B5wJ
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
          <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 00 0%">
            <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" class="icon-display">check_circle_outline </mat-icon>
          </div>
          <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 100%">
            <span class="password-meter">8 characters mininum</span>
          </div>
        </div>

Comment: @JhonCaylog please post a new question for that

Comment: I could no longer post bro..can you please help me with that ?

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs